# How can Asp Net Core serve html static pages?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have recently started an `Asp .Net Core` app. Later I wanted to integrate it with Angular, but first I wanted a mechanism that will 'replace' `cshtml` with `html`.

If I change extension from `cshtml` to `html` I get this

> 'InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found'.

Also I tried in Startup

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");      
});
```

but it also didn't work.

Optional is to integrating cshtml layout content with html pages, but I think this is impossible.

So, my question is, can I simply replace all cshtml with html?

Answer (score 22):

Static files are typically located in the web root (wwwroot) folder.By default, that is the only place where we can serve up files directly from the file system.

1.create a `html` file inside (wwwroot) name `index.html`

2.install `Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles` package via NuGet

3.Add `UseStaticFiles` in `Startup.cs` under Configure methode

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    // if you want to run outside wwwroot then use this
    //request like http://<app>/StaticFiles/index.html
   /* app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"MyStaticFiles")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles")
    });*/
}
```

if you want to run Static Files outside `wwwroot`, then-

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    //request like http://<app>/StaticFiles/index.html
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"MyStaticFiles")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/StaticFiles")
    });
}
```

your request like `http://<app>/StaticFiles/index.html`

if you want `index.html` to be your default file, this is a feature that IIS has always had,then

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)  { 
   app.UseIISPlatformHandler();  
   app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); 

   app.UseRuntimeInfoPage();  
   app.UseDefaultFiles(); 
   app.UseStaticFiles();

}
```

hopefully it's help you. You can more information from [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_static_files.htm) link.

Comment: How do you server index.cshtml?

Comment: @Reft you can more information about chtml from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/mvc?view=aspnetcore-2.1.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2