# How to add .html url suffix to all Razor pages in ASP.NET Core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC app using Razor pages stored in the project tree under the /Pages folder.

The project is set up using default routing etc.

I would like to all the Razor pages to have .html extension in the browser's address bar.

File /Pages/test.cshtml is currently available via http://localhost/test. I would like this page to be available via http://localhost/test.html instead.

I tried to understand the routing settings but failed to understand it enough to come with the solution.

What should I write where so the files are available via .html suffix?

Comment: Any particular reason you need them to end that way? It's not the normal way for MVC applications. This has the beginnings of an X/Y Problem.

Comment: Url stability. What're the possible issues with having .html suffixes in urls?

Comment: Url stability ~ the site already exists as pure static pages. The site is currently reimplemented as an ASP.NET Core 2 MVC project. I prefer to keep the external urls unchanged.

Comment: Have you considered setting up some kind of redirect rule for this?

Answer (score 3):

defined a route for this as follows

```
routes.MapRoute(
"MyHtml",
"{controller}/{action}.html",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

and add `HtmlFileHandler` to web.config. And `.html` routes work now.

```
<handlers>
  <add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: Confirm with OP is they are referring to standard routing or *Razor Pages*. the routing is different between the two.

Comment: Thanks, great idea. I tested it for controllers and it seems to work. However, I was originally talking about Razor Pages, not about Views based on controllers.

Comment: @alik Maybe this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915637/how-can-asp-net-core-serve-html-static-pages?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: It does not help. It talks about static pages located typically inside the wwwroot folder. My files are dynamic with a cshtml extension, optionally backed by a C# model (but not a controller), they have support for master pages (typically _Layout.cshtml) and they are expected inside a /Pages folder.